# Tail-log backup options when restoring to a new database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I want to restore a sql server database(sql server 2014) to a new database to see if I can recover deleted data.

I need to restore from about 2 months ago, so I will need to use the timeline and pick the correct trn point in time.

I'm restoring to a new database and don't want to mess with or interrupt the source database at all.

So should I leave the options under Tail-log backup (Take tail-log backup before restore and Leave source database in the restoring state) unchecked or checked?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I'm restoring to a new database and don't want to mess with or interrupt the source database at all.
>
> So should I leave the options under Tail-log backup (Take tail-log
>   backup before restore and Leave source database in the restoring
>   state) unchecked or checked?

Unchecked.  Just enter the name of the new database you want to restore into and pick the point on the timeline.

Comment: Any idea why it defaults to 'Take tail-log backup...' when the destination database is different from source? Seems unlikely to be desired.